# angularjs ng-parttern not show css highlight error or success

Tags: angularjs, validation

Have html code like below

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="myform">
<div class="modal-body" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group" >
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-username">Username (*)</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="username" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,10}$/" placeholder="Username" id="input-username" class="form-control" data-ng-model="newuser.username">
            <div class="help-block">Username must be 4-10 characters.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

using ng-pattern copy in an example but it not right work for me, when type in under 4 character, html css not highlight red border, and when type in 4 character css not highlitght green border. I don't know why I can not show right css

Comment: Could you add the related CSS you are using to this example?

Comment: @musically_ut : hi it's worked, I changed 
    class="form-horizontal"
to 
    class="form-validation"
and it's work well :)

Answer (score 0):

Patters arent usually used for checking length... You can do ng-minlength and ng-maxlength for that like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="myform">
<div class="modal-body" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group" >
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-username">Username (*)</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="username" ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="10" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,10}$/" placeholder="Username" id="input-username" class="form-control" data-ng-model="newuser.username">
            <div class="help-block" ng-if="myform.$invalid">Username must be 4-10 characters.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```